# WebStorm opens files on AutoScroll to source

Tags: webstorm, adobe-brackets

wondering if I could have the same behavior as Brackets like it previews the code on the right side but only opens the file if we do some edits.

Helpful when I'm just going through the files and not really changing anything but then at the end I've to close all.

Is there a setting in web storm that can help achieve the same behavior like brackets

Comment: You can use `View | Quick Definition` to preview file content instead of opening (has to be invoked for each file, which is possibly not what you are willing to do). Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130918

Comment: got it, hope they introduce this feature, they should have looked around what other IDE's are offering while developing this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I may only suggest to use `View | Quick Definition` to preview file content instead of opening (has to be invoked for each file, which is possibly not what you are willing to do).

Other than that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130918 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

**P.S.**
As stated in [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130918#comment=27-814400) they seems to worked on something like that already but quite possibly did not finished it for IDEA v14 release: in build 138.2502 there was an option to open file in "preview panel" first (and if satisfied -- move to editor) instead of opening in editor straight away. But it still a bit different to what Sublime does.